# Why does an occur happen in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

An error occcured in line6.

Please tell me how to change.

Google Apps Script below.
https://script.google.com/home/projects/1ajXz8eBPngMhL52cnf_au5ZSSG4riqRSteAkEKXdn7iFIB66JDME8I3N/edit

```
function sato() {
  let sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ACPH9X5-u_FYPKcVujnx_M-EKGxZwUD3a8SQ3FVxwE8');
  let sheets = sh.getSheets;

  for (let i = 1; i < 12; i++) {  
    let rowNum = sheets[i].getRange(4,7,1,1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow()-3;
    let range = sheets[i].getRange(4, 7, rowNum, 1);
    let iValues = range.getValues();
    const oValues = [];
    for (let y = 0; y < rowNum; y++) {
      let redirectUrl = getRedirect(iValues[y][0]);
      oValues.push([redirectUrl]);
    }
    console.log(i);
    sheets[i].getRange(4, 8, rowNum, 1).setValues(oValues);
  }
}

function getRedirect(url) {

  console.log(url);


  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { 'followRedirects': false, 'muteHttpExceptions': false });
  var redirectUrl = response.getHeaders()['Location'];  // undefined if no redirect, so... 
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();        // ...it calls itself recursively...
  if (redirectUrl) {                                    // ...if redirected... 
    var nextRedirectUrl = redirectUrl;
    return nextRedirectUrl;
  } else {                                              // ...until it's not 
    return url;
  }
}
```

Comment: When I saw your script, `let sheets = sh.getSheets;` is not used as the method. When you modify it to `let sheets = sh.getSheets();`, will your issue of `An error occcured in line6.` be resulved? But, I think that if your Spreadsheet has no more than 13 sheets, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Also, I think that this document might be useful. [Ref1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) and [Ref2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#calling_functions)

Comment: This `sh.getSheets` should be `sh.getSheets();`